# C# auto billno using winform

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    public void AutoBillNo()
    {
        int billno = 0;
        billno++;
        txtBillNo.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(txtBillNo.Text) + 1);
    }


    private void Bill_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
       AutoBillNo();
    }
```

It works properly  but  after rerun winform textbox shows
1 . It not show increase value in textbox. what will I do?

Comment: are storing it anywhere in database?

Answer (score 1):

Make your billno to be global variable (move
int billno = 0;
out ofthe method). 
Now you create it on each run.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the variable billno in this code is not assigned to the text box.

When you rerun the same the txtBillNo.Text is again initialized to zero.

```
int billno = 0;
billno++;
txtBillNo.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt64(txtBillNo.Text) + 1);`
```

This should rather be

```
 static int billno = 0;
 billno++;
 txtBillNo.Text = Convert.ToString(bilno);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are never using billno. You are always taking the value from the textbox.

I would do the following:

```
private static int billno = 1;
public void AutoBillNo()
{
     txtBillNo.Text = billno.ToString();
     ++billno;
}
```

But be aware,if you restart your programm the billno is 1 again...
If you need to keep the billno you have to store it somewhere.